# How do I set the [popup] parameter on a Knowledge article to false?

Tags: knowledge, partner-portal, articles

In the Knowledge Articles "Search Results" the URL for each article includes the parameter `popup` with a value of `true` and I am interested in rendering the parameter value as `false` so that the article is displayed with the header intact when the user clicks the link.

Where is this parameter controlled from the Setup menu?

It seems impossible to Google any useful information on the topic and I am unable to locate anything in the org which would dictate that is controllable.

I suspect that I will need to manipulate the markup with JavaScript to achieve the behavior I desire.

Is this true?

Comment: You can't configure this from the setup. The only way I can think of doing this is with javascript but if you are referring to the standard articles page I don't see how would you add that code somewhere in the page. What do you mean by displaying the article with the header intact, what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: The article is displayed in a portal with a highly customized UI, when an article is opened with this parameter set `true` it's incredibly ugly. The parameter removes all of the portal branding on the article detail page that would normally be displayed (and is displayed on the article search page). The detail page is stripped of all the elements that would be unnecessary if you rendered the article in a popup dialog. Similar to `/{Id}/m?isAjaxRequest=1` and `/{Id}?isdtp=vw`. Getting JavaScript into the page isn't an issue but I would rather not do it if there exists a native mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having read your last comment, this cannot be done from the setup. You will need to use JavaScript

Comment: can you add some code sample as of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran across this problem when enabling Knowledge in a Salesforce Customer Community.  After some research and a salesforce support ticket, it was determined that if you give the Profile of the User, Knowledge One permission, the problem is resolved.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "resolved" means? What is the effect of giving the user Knowledge One permission?